The English SE font is unable to display letters with macron and acute correctly
I do not mind the font choice on English SE at all; it provides character to the community and is, if I am not mistaken, Georgia, which was specifically designed for screens. However, it is lacking. English, having borrowed heavily from Greek and Latin, is in need of a font that is able to display romanised Greek well on a site such as English SE.
Below is an image of the comment section where this came up (link further down):

Figure 1: Comment section from Is there a term for ‘Era when the gods walked amongst men’? showing how the vowels are not displayed correctly on site, but do display correctly whilst typing them.
There are two parts to this image: one the posted comment, one the edit field. Observe the following:

In the comment, ánthrṓpōn¹ and ánthrō´pōn² are not written the same.
If they were displayed correctly, 1 would display as 9 characters and 2 would display as 10 characters.
Both 1 and 2 are instead, in the posted comment displayed as 10 characters (and will most likely be here as well).

In the following examples, I will include the macron and acute for all the Greek vowels:

a, ā, ā́, reversed á̄
e, ē, ḗ, reversed é̄
i, ī, ī́, reversed í̄
o, ō, ṓ, reversed ó̄
u, ū, ū́, reversed ú̄
y, ȳ, ȳ́, reversed ý̄

If this displays as expected by the ‘bug’, only y will display all four alternatives correctly. The below is an image of the same list:

Figure 2: How the above list is displayed, demonstrating how the font fails.
What is interesting to take note of, is that the font in the comment edit field works just fine. Obviously the problem does not lie with how the characters are encoded, but with the display font. I therefore ask these questions:

Is this only a problem on my machine or can it be verified by others?
If the latter, how can this be solved on English SE?


It’s just you :—}

Notice for me your selection from the comments renders very differently from what you posted above in the question:

It is not necessary that Georgia do all things: your system should be using a reasonable glyph-substitution algorithm that knows how to pull in missing glyphs from other fonts of yours, plus how to do combining characters.
What system are you using?
They are only sometimes using Georgia. Technically the font choice is:
 font-family: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", Times, serif

and in that order. So if you lacked Georgia, it would use Cambria et cetera right on down the line.

Possible Workaround
I do note that you are using fully decomposed forms (NFD format):

a, a\N{COMBINING MACRON}, a\N{COMBINING MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed a\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
e, e\N{COMBINING MACRON}, e\N{COMBINING MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed e\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
i, i\N{COMBINING MACRON}, i\N{COMBINING MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed i\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
o, o\N{COMBINING MACRON}, o\N{COMBINING MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed o\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
u, u\N{COMBINING MACRON}, u\N{COMBINING MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed u\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
y, y\N{COMBINING MACRON}, y\N{COMBINING MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed y\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}\N{COMBINING MACRON}

You might instead try using the maximally composed forms (NFC format) to see whether that doesn’t make a difference:

a, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH MACRON}, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
e, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH MACRON}, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH MACRON AND ACUTE}, reversed \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
i, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH MACRON}, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
o, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH MACRON}, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH MACRON AND ACUTE}, reversed \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
u, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH MACRON}, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE}\N{COMBINING MACRON}
y, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH MACRON}, \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH MACRON}\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}, reversed \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH ACUTE}\N{COMBINING MACRON}

Here’s what that looks like in NFC:

a, ā, ā́, reversed á̄
e, ē, ḗ, reversed é̄
i, ī, ī́, reversed í̄
o, ō, ṓ, reversed ó̄
u, ū, ū́, reversed ú̄
y, ȳ, ȳ́, reversed ý̄

That shouldn’t ever make a difference with any modern, Unicode-aware rendering engine, and indeed for me those look exactly the same in NFC as the ones you posted in NFD look. Perhaps your system isn’t very good with this? Again, what are you using? I’m on a simple Mac here, but I’ve seen legacy Windows systems and old telephones mess it up.
I honestly can’t think of what Stack Exchange could change here that would help you. They cannot change to a non-system typeface that not everybody might have, like something included only with Adobe products installed on some systems.
And historically they have not looked favorably on pulling in a “network font” from Google etc.

I am on a Windows 10 x64 (v. 10.0.19045.4412]) PC (AMD Ryzen 5 3600, 48 GiB 3200 MHz DDR4 RAM, PowerColor Red Devil RX 5600 XT (Radeon software version 24.4.1)). It is not the latest and greatest, but definitely not a legacy system. I do have Georgia installed as a system font, though it behaves the same way in Writer as here. My guess is that if I install it from Google Fonts, it will fix the problem. [–––] Turns out it is not there. Then what? In any case, the font would presumably be linked in the style sheet of SE, wouldn’t it? What could be causing this?

Let me try it in a couple more browsers (this is Opera GX). Now tested in the latest versions of Opera, Edge and Chrome, and I get the same result in all of them. And yes, I completely agree with what you say: ‘That shouldn’t ever make a difference with any modern, Unicode-aware rendering engine’. But at least for me, it does. Surely I’m not the only one. Maybe we are a very small minority, but still.

Oh shucks then it's likely the operating system, not the web browser! I've heard no end of sad stories like yours in this particular area coming from users of Microsoft systems. Something they're doing "wrong" in the rendering of such things that Apple—and often these days even Linux—systems manage to get right. I don't know the details, however, as this is nothing I've ever had to face on my own because I've never used them. I’m sorry. It’s possible that you could get better technical answers to this problem on an SE site like [graphicdesign.se], or even staff support on [meta.se].

I think it's a problem with the Windows implementation of Georgia -- which is a bit surprising, since it's a Microsoft font. I see the same as @CannedMan on my W10 system. I played with removing bits of the CSS and ended up with Segoe UI and Times which both display correctly.

@AndrewLeach If you could post that as an answer (including your process), I believe that would be helpful.

Any other Windows users experiencing the same thing that @AndrewLeach and I are?

I am using Ubunt, but I have the same issue, even though I installed the Georgia font. Fun fact, it happens with Microsoft Edge, but not with Firefox.
